# What could be controlling the placement of an absolutely positioned element besides left/right/top/bottom?

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to track down the styling controlling a page element in some very old Angular code I've inherited, and I'm quite stuck.

It's an absolutely positioned element *without* `left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom` defined on it. If you check inherited CSS properties in the Chrome inspector, these are all set to `auto`.

The nearest relative or absolutely positioned ancestor is a gigantic `position: relative` div that spans the whole page and contains everything.

And yet, somehow, this tiny element is in exactly the right place. I checked `getBoundingClientRect()` and somehow bottom is 632.95, left is 779.1, right is 975.04, and top is 608.95. I'm at a loss for where these values are coming from and what's putting the element in the right place.

Any suggestions? I've tagged this with Angular in case someone knows of something in the Angular framework that might be involved -- this is an error message appearing next to a form, FWIW.

Comment: What does the chrome dev-tools say? Is display inline-block or it within a table? bootstrap? transform: translate()? float?

Comment: `display:block` for the element itself and all ancestors. No float, no translate or transform.

Comment: Margins/padding/border/box-sizing possibly? Without some code not much to go on.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but impossible to share. Maybe....maybe it has something to do with the `before` and `after`...hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer can be seen from the spec.
The standard generally says if top/bottom, left/right are auto, then default them to their `position: static` values:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

Comment: If I turn off `position: absolute`, the element indeed stays where it is once it becomes static, and the only change is that its width expands to fill the parent div, whereas when `position: absolute` is on its width is that of the text inside it. Can you account for that?

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning really just means the element is no longer part of the normal document flow. `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`--while convenient for positioning--aren't the only way to move elements around the page.

borders, margins, and padding will all push an element, but the far more likely candidate is [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). `translate` has a number of highly convenient values for positioning, specifically `translateX` and `translateY`, although they are really just a shorthand for `matrix`, which is much less discernible and easy to miss.

Another thought is to be sure to check your computed values for `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`, just in case a higher specificity selector or inline-style is overriding what you think is the current value.